# Send mail with mutt in shell script file

Tags: shell, mutt

I am writing the following command in .sh file and it opens the interactive window to ask me to input an email address to send the email. The email is then sent with the attached file without issue.

```
mutt -s 'risk items' -a file.xlsx
```

But if I try the following command it fails to send it bypassing the interactive window.

```
mutt -s 'risk items' -a file.xlsx my_name@company_name.com
```

Also the second command is working outside shell. Any help to solve this would be appreciated.

The error message is:

```
my_name@company_name.com: unable to attach file.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect. Look at the output of `mutt -h`, which should include something like this:

```
mutt [<options>] [-Ex] [-Hi <file>] [-s <subj>] [-bc <addr>] [-a <file> [...] --] <addr> [...]
```

Look at the `-a` argument, which shows `-a <file> [...] --`.

The `-a` argument expects multiple files. You use `--` to terminate the list so that mutt knows you've stopped listing files and are now listing addresses:

```
mutt -s 'risk items' -a file.xlsx -- my_name@company_name.com
```

Comment: thank you for your help. Still It seems to open the interactive window and pre file  the email address for me. Is there a way to skip the interactive window please?

Comment: solved by adding < /dev/null before the email address

Answer (score 0):

My last experience with mutt was `v 1.13.2` in an Ubuntu svr. It had no issues with this batch mode / interactive mode / window mode or whatever else its called.

2 ways to get out of that mode ( needed for bash scripts )

```
* < /dev/null BEFORE the to_email_recipient ( as commented above )
* echo "" | mutt options to_email_recipient
```

Sample mutt command ( Skip reading system muttrc file( -n)  and use a custom file ( -F ).

```
mutt -n -F $CONFIG_FILE -s "SUBJECT: Something Something "  -i $BODY_FILE  -c $CC_RECIPIENT_EMAIL  </dev/null $MAIN_RECIPIENT_EMAIL    -a $ATTACHMENT1 -a $ATTACHMENT2
```

Important Parameters for muttrc ( mail server that uses STARTTLS )

```
# SMTP Credentials
# port 587 -> smtp:// port 465 -> smtps://

set smtp_url = "smtp://notice_email@somedomain.com@mail.somedomain.com:587/"
set smtp_pass = "some_passwd"

# SMTP Parameters - Important

set smtp_authenticators = "plain:login"
set certificate_file = /misc/mail/certificates

set ssl_starttls = yes
set ssl_force_tls = yes

set ssl_verify_host = no
set ssl_verify_dates = no
```

GPG can be used for the passwd but I choose not too in my use case.
Additionally mutt/SMTP debugging can be done with flag -d N, where N is 1 to 5 as follows;

```
mutt -n -d 5 -F $CONFIG_FILE -s "SUBJECT: Something Something "  -i $BODY_FILE  -c $CC_RECIPIENT_EMAIL  </dev/null $MAIN_RECIPIENT_EMAIL    -a $ATTACHMENT1 -a $ATTACHMENT2
```